# Could not find sub module [xxx.jar] as defined in application.xml

Tags: java, maven, deployment

I have a project running on Glassfish in my Intellij and it's currently running version `9.5.0` in Application.xml

When I changed my projects to `9.7.0`, I can rebuild the project with no errors but when I tried to run it, it throws this:

```
Exception while deploying the app [Application-9.7.0] : Could not find sub module [Panton9-ejb-9.5.0.jar] as defined in application.xml]]
```

I changed every module's pom.xml to 9.7.0 and they didn't display any error but just for this particular sub module. I can't figure out what I did wrong, as I double checked the version and it's all set to 9.7.0.

This is my application.xml:

```
 <dependencies>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>com.htasia</groupId>
        <artifactId>Panton9-ejb</artifactId>
        <version>9.7.0</version>
        <type>ejb</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.htasia</groupId>
        <artifactId>Generic</artifactId>
        <version>9.7.0</version>
        <type>war</type>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.htasia</groupId>
            <artifactId>PantonNotify</artifactId>
            <version>9.7.0</version>
            <type>ejb</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.htasia</groupId>
            <artifactId>PantonMCRE</artifactId>
            <version>9.7.0</version>
            <type>ejb</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.htasia</groupId>
            <artifactId>PantonForm</artifactId>
            <version>9.7.0</version>
            <type>ejb</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.htasia</groupId>
            <artifactId>PantonWorkflow</artifactId>
            <version>9.7.0</version>
            <type>ejb</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: Does the app work if you build it with Maven and deploy manually, outside of IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: I haven't tried this yet but I know this can't be an issue with my glassfish server since it works with my old version(9.5.0) but not with this new version. I must be missing something here.

Comment: This will help to narrow down the problem to see whether the issue is with the Maven project configuration or with IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: Okay I need to deploy outside of IDE right?

Comment: Yes, build/deploy from Maven and see if the result is the same.

Comment: Alright give me a moment and i'll get back to u

Comment: My application.ear is `application 9.5.0.ear` is it supposed to be changed to 9.7.0 if I changed my maven versions?

Comment: It should be according to the pattern https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/examples/customize-file-name-mapping.html.

Comment: I have two ear files in my target folder: 9.5.0 ear and 9.7.0 ear, i should be using the new one and delete the old one?

Comment: So I tried running it outside my IDE by placing the 9.7.0 ear file into the glassfish domain and it says auto deploy failed.

Comment: OK, it means the issue is not IntelliJ IDEA specific. Someone else experienced in Maven will probably help you here.